# Dynamically Assigning the Style to the TabItem Control

Tags: wpf, tabitem

I have a style defined in App.xaml file "tabControlStyle". How can I assign this style to my dynamically created TabItem control.

```
 TabItem item = new TabItem();               



                item.Header = String.Format("Item {0}", i);
                documentTab.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: No longer relevant, IMO, means that the question is out of date, not that you found an answer. Reopening so other people, if they have alternative solutions, can post them.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. Here it is:

```
 private void PopulateTabControl()
        {
            for(int i=1; i<=10;i++)
            {
                TabItem item = new TabItem();
                item.Style = Application.Current.Resources["tabItemStyle"] as Style;
                item.Header = String.Format("Item {0}", i);
                documentTab.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
```